# Why isn't flash updating the display while the mouse is clicked and moving?

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2, transparent

I have a flash clip that moves a movieclip when the mouse is clicked on the movieclip. Something very basic.

I'm not using drag (since the MC doesn't move with the mouse all the time), but rather using onMouseMove to update the MC location according to _xmouse, _ymouse and some other calculations.

The problem was that under internet explorer the movement became very slow and if I kept moving the mouse slowly, it wouldn't update until I stopped.

I checked the traces and the event was triggered properly.
I tried using updateAfterEvent();  Didn't help.

This didn't happen in firefox.

(After a long, frustrating debugging I eventually found out what caused this. Since I've looked for the answer online and didn't find one, I've decided to add it here for others.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior happens when the movie is specified in the HTML container as 'transparent'. Setting it to 'window' solves this problem.

I still don't know why the "slow effect" didn't happen in firefox, maybe the firefox flash plugin handles transparency better.